# changing numpy array column headings

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ta-lib, metatrader5

Help with changing numpy array column headings. this is my code - I'm trying to plot this data from MT5 and I'm using matplotlib.pyplot and mplfinance for plotting the data in bbands. but apparently mplfinance only wants 'date','open','high','low','close' columns in order to plot the data. is there another work around? thanks!

This is the code:

```py
# Extract n Ticks before now
rates = mt5.copy_rates_from("EURUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_D1, from_date, 15)

#Transform Tuple into a DataFrame
df_rates = pd.DataFrame(rates)

#convert to numpy array
data = df_rates["close"].values

#Convert number format of the date into date format
df_rates["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_rates["time"], unit="s")

#create new dataframe with the columns in correct format
df_candle = df_rates[['time','open','high','low','close']]
df_candle.columns = ['date','open','high','low','close']
df_candle['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_candle['date'], unit='s')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the columns as you are doing, which should work fine.

Alternatively you can pass `columns=('MyOpen','MyHigh','MyLow','MyClose','MyVolume')` into `mpf.plot()` which tells mplfinance what column names to use for open, high, low, close, and volume.

Note: It appears to me that since your columns are already named "open", "high", "low" and "close" then you do *not* have to re-name them, nor do you have to pass in the `columns` kwarg.

Perhaps the problem is that your dataframe does not have a datetime index?

As with your previous question, because you are ***not showing your data*** it is very difficult for anyone to definitely say what needs to change.  Always show your data.  Without it, your question is incomplete.

Comment: open high low close tick_volume spread real_volumetime       
2023-01-12 14:59:00 1.07614 1.07614 1.07595 1.07607 76 1 0
2023-01-12 15:00:00 1.07607 1.07619 1.07601 1.07617 102 1 0
2023-01-12 15:01:00 1.07615 1.07618 1.07601 1.07617 82 1 0